# Azure CI build error C1189

Tags: azure

the problem is the following,
I have one vs2017 solution that correctly runs at my local machine.
this solution contains multiples c++ and c# projects.

I'm trying to build the same solution at Azure CI, but the build fails. it shows me this error at one .CPP file

Error C1189: #error:  'You must redo this OnClose so it works with your version of MFC'

As the solution work when it runs locally I just do not understand what should I do (setup into azure) in order to correctly build the solution into Azure.

[VS2017 Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq2z0.png)

[Azure Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSl3m.png)

do this error say something to anybody?

thx.

Sorry for my rusty English.